# Magnolia CMS - Module Creation technique for creating templates

Tags: module, content-management-system, magnolia

need to create templates based on magnolia standard templating kit...by watching other modules in built in Magnolia...

can i get a start here from any of our folks.....or some steps to catch up with...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am a newbie to CMS & also to Magnolia....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the documentation at http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com most specifically the technical guide's section on STK: http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/technical-guide/stk.html

If you still have questions i suggest to use http://forum.magnolia-cms.com